# Will importing a function from module foo also import all modules imported in foo?

Tags: python, module, python-import

Suppose I have a module `foo.py` as follows:

```
import somemodule

def func1():
   # uses somemodule
   ...

def func2():
   # does NOT use somemodule
   ...
```

Now if start a new .py file and say:

```
from foo import func2
...
```

will `somemodule` be imported too even though it is not necessary?
If yes, could it be avoided?

I'm asking because I want to use just 1 function from a large module (seaborn, which takes few seconds to load) and don't want to load the giant thing for to use that 1 function.

Comment: did you try it yourself and see?

Comment: I'm afraid so, importing the module needs to evaluate the whole module, you can use some kind of lazy loading technique if you need a boost in speed

Comment: It'd require a very expensive dependency analysis to even try to figure out what parts of a module any import really needs, and trying to get it completely right is undecidable.